# PostgreSQL using variables

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE type = 0) as first_sum,
       COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE type = 0) as second_sum,
       first_sum + second_sum as final_sum
FROM ...
```

Is it possible to use some kind of **variables** to make this work?

Comment: How about `COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE type = 0) + COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE type = 0)`?  Of course this will result in a null if either argument is null.  Your example has them both with the same criteria, but presumably that's not what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly possible, the technique is called “subquery”:

```
SELECT first_sum,
       second_sum,
       first_sum + second_sum AS final_sum
FROM (SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 0) AS first_sum,
             count(*) FILTER (WHERE type = 0) AS second_sum
      FROM ...
     ) AS subq;
```

Comment: Ok thanks! That's what I thought. :) I was just wondering if there is any other (better) way.